# SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE

Tags: android

I'm trying to install my app debug from my android studio. it works well yesterday, but today when I try to install it again, the application cant be installed on my device and shows errors like below on my android studio.

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE
The device timed out while trying to install the application.
Retry
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Virtual device. This error will not occur.